# Using pandas how to iterate over 2 spare-vector rows, compute using scipy and save to new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy

Wishing you guys have spent safe and happy x-mas;

I have sparse vector of embedded sentences on pandas DataFrame like below;

```
title_emb                                           text_emb
[[2, 6294, 4076, 346, 10231, 16068, 8654, 1191...   [[2, 11830, 18726, 16331, 4474, 4083, 2654, 41...
[[2, 6451, 6230, 2513, 107, 12202, 6538, 4176,...   [[2, 10082, 29402, 4039, 21982, 23, 4029, 6766...
...
[[2, 8403, 8569, 4234, 6706, 4482, 23033, 4136...   [[2, 8569, 4234, 6706, 4482, 145, 23033, 4136,...
175846 rows × 2 columns
```

I would like to add different kinds of similarities using scipy.spatial.distance.cdist library and meet errorst that my given data is not 2-dimension array.

Looking at the scipy doc, cdist(XA,XB,'similarity_name') which XA and XB are 2-dim sparse vector

```
train['euclidean'] = cdist(train['title_emb'],train['text_emb'], 'euclidean')
train['cosine'] = cdist(train['title_emb'],train['text_emb'], 'cosine')
train['hamming'] = cdist(train['title_emb'],train['text_emb'], 'hamming')
train['jaccard'] = cdist(train['title_emb'],train['text_emb'], 'jaccard')
```

This gives error but below doesn't

```
print(cdist(train['title_emb'][175846],train['text_emb'][175846], 'euclidean'))
print(cdist(train['title_emb'][175846],train['text_emb'][175846], 'cosine'))
print(cdist(train['title_emb'][175846],train['text_emb'][175846], 'jaccard'))
```

Which should be the fastest way to compute and save it to DataFrame?

1. use for loop, save to list and put it to DataFrame
2. use df.iterrow, save to list and put it to DataFrame
3. is there way to fix above code and save it to DataFrame directly?
4. other way like df.apply(**function**)

Comment: i think a simple `for` loop would be a better idea.

Comment: which should i use? index / loc / iloc / iterrows / itertuples

Comment: try `train['euclidean'] = train.apply(lambda x: cdist(x.title_emb, x.text_emb), axis=1)`

Comment: thanks ;)  I have tried all of them and seems itertuples is faster then apply